# Remove redundant String from array string

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I want to remove the existing string contains in string array. 
For example:

string array contains:

```
string [] arra = new string[] {"Financial banking", "mobile application", "customer account opening", "financial", "banking", "mobile", "application", "account banking"};
```

Want result like:

```
string [] result = new string[] {"Financial banking", "mobile application", "customer account opening"}
```

Want to remove:

```
financial, banking, mobile, application, account banking
```

As these string already present in string array

I have tried below code:

```
string [] arra = new string[] {"Financial banking", "mobile application", "customer account opening", "financial", "banking", "mobile", "application", "account banking"};
string [] arrb = new string[] {"Financial banking", "mobile application", "customer account opening", "financial", "banking", "mobile", "application", "account banking"};
List<string> resultarr = new List<string>();

foreach(var arralist in arra){
    foreach(var arrblist in arrb){
        if(!arralist.Contains(arrblist) && !resultarr.Contains(arrblist)){
            resultarr.Add(arrblist);
            Console.WriteLine(arrblist);
        }
    }
}
```

But it is not return desired result. Any help on this.

Comment: If you need to add & remove items then it is better to store the data as a collection such as a List.  You can still easily convert it to an array if needed by specific functions.

Comment: Your rule is unclear or at least incomplete. You say _"as these string already present in string array"_, but the string "account banking" is **not** present in the array. Both space-separated strings are present _inside_ other strings earlier in the array, but that's a quite significant difference.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that your algorithm is:

1. Break each element in your input into words (separated by spaces)
2. If we've seen all of those words before (case-insensitive), then ignore that element
3. Otherwise, add that element to the output, and remember all of those words

This produces your expected output, but it might be worth clarifying your algorithm in your question.

If this is correct, you can do something like this:

```
var input = new string[] {"Financial banking", "mobile application", "customer account opening", "financial", "banking", "mobile", "application", "account banking"};
var wordsSeen = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
var result = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in input)
{
    var words = item.Split(' ');

    // If all of the elements in 'words' are present in 'wordsSeen', ignore this item
    if (wordsSeen.IsProperSupersetOf(words))
        continue;

    result.Add(item);

    // Add all of these words to 'seen'
    wordsSeen.UnionWith(words);
}
```

We use a [`HashSet<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.8) to record the words that we've seen, and we tell it to use the [`StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.invariantcultureignorecase?view=netframework-4.8) comparer when doing comparisons between words, so it will say that two words are the same even if they're using different case. (You may want to use [`StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.currentcultureignorecase?view=netframework-4.8) or [`StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase?view=netframework-4.8) here.)

Comment: Only extra point I'd say is `2. If we've seen ANY of those words before, ignore...`. I'm thinking in the case of `customer account opening` existing and `account` cropping up.

Comment: @scgough Why? I interpreted the requirement as being "ALL", and my code does "ALL". The question is unclear on this point, and I interpreted it in a particularly way, stated that, and wrote code against it. You may disagree on the interpretation of the question, but that doesn't change my answer.

Comment: Totally understood. Not picking holes. Your answer is the correct answer (I upvoted). I noted just in case the interpretation should be 'any' rather than 'all' (as that's how I read it).

Answer (score 0):

And what about the [`Distinct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8) method:

```
var result = arra.Distinct(new DistinctItemComparer()).ToArray();
```

However you might also need to use a custom equality comparer for this purpose.

```
public class DistinctItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{

    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        return y.ToLower().Split().Any(c => x.ToLower().Contains(c));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

See the result here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/FoC0C5

Answer (score -1):

If your sole aim is to remove the Redundant elements. Then you can try this:

```
string [] arra = new string[] {"Financial banking", "mobile application", "customer account opening", "financial", "banking", "mobile", "application", "account banking"};
var elementsToRemove = new string[]{"financial", "banking", "mobile", "application", "account banking"};
var newArray = arra.Except(elementsToRemove).ToArray();
```

You will need to bring in `System.Ling` namespace to access the `Except` method.